# Условная вероятность нормального распределения

Tags: python, теория-вероятностей

Всем привет, возник вопрос на счет условной вероятности непрерывной случайной величины. У меня есть две случайной величины изображенной на картинке, правильно ли я понимаю, что используя функцию stats.normal().pdf из scipy я найду условную вероятность Y|X, для каждого смоделированного X? и еще один вопрос, если я найду pdf X|Y, то я получу таблицу условной вероятности?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под условной вероятностью `Y|X`, если X и Y - непрерывные величины?

Comment: @Chorkov на картинке Y это нормальное распределение зависящие от X, получается что интеграл по плотности вероятности этого распределения должно быть условной вероятностью

Comment: Условная вероятность может быть для события `Y>y|X>x` (как функция двух переменных x, y) или `Y>y|X==x`.  (Справа от `|` должна быть случайная булева величина).

Comment: @Chorkov в таком случае как можно составить таблицу условных вероятностей для такого распределения Y? Просто находить pdf для каждого Y|X ==xi?

Comment: `P(Y==y|X==x)` :  `scipy.stats.norm(1. +3.5*x., 1.).pdf(y) ` , но боюсь, что от вас требуется что-то иное.